# On the conditions of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Let $F(x,y)$ be a function and let $P=(x_{0},y_{0})$ be a point on the curve $F(x,y)=0$. The implicit function theorem tells us that if $F(x,y)$ satisfies the following two conditions:

(1)  $F(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable on a neighbourhood of $P$;

(2) $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\neq0$.

Then for the curve $F(x,y)=0$ around $(x_0, y_0)$, we can write $y=f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a real function.

My question is, if we change the first condition to: $F(x,y)$ is just differentiable at $P$, the partial derivative of $F$ maybe not continuous, can we determine an implicit function in the neighborhood of point $P$(here we don't care about whether the implicit function is derivable)?

Comment: Do you know any examples of a differentiable function with a partial derivative that is not continuous?

Comment: For the existence of an implicit function all you need is $F(x,y)$ strictly monotonic with respect to $y$ in some neighborhood of the point. But, even in one dimension, differentiability with positive derivative at a point does not guarantee monotonicity near the point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Function like this $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2})$, but the partial derivative of $y$ at $(0,0)$ is zero.

Comment: Consider a function like $g(y)=\begin{cases} y/2 + y^2\sin(1/y), & y\ne 0 \\ 0, & y=0\end{cases}$. Now think what to use for $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin@GReyes  Let $F(x,y)=g(y)+\sin x$, $F_y(0,0)=1\neq0$. $F(x,y)$ is differentiable but the partial derivative of $F(x,y)$ w.r.t $y$ is not continuous and $F_y(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ is not zero. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Well, $F_y$ isn’t $1$, but …. Why don’t you write a complete answer?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, $F_y$ is $1/2$ and I write down the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite the answers of Ted Shifrin and GReyes. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions, then $F(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ is a differentiable function of two variables and we have that
$$F_x(x,y)=f'(x),\qquad F_y(x,y)=g'(y).$$
Thus, if one of $f'(x)$ and $g'(y)$ is not continuous, then $F(x,y)$ is a differentiable function but not a $C^1$ function. Now let
$$f(x)=\sin x,\quad g(y)=\begin{cases}y/2+y^2\sin(1/y),&y\neq 0\\
0,&y=0\end{cases}$$
and
$$F(x,y)=f(x)+g(y),$$
then
$$F_y(x,y)=\begin{cases}1/2+2y\sin(1/y)-\cos(1/y),&y\neq 0\\
1/2,&y=0\end{cases}.$$
Special, $F_y(0,0)=1/2\neq0$. But in any neighbour $U$ of point $(0,0)$, $y$ is not a function of $x$. In fact, for any neighbour $(-\delta,\delta)$ of $x=0$ and every point $x_0\in(-\delta,\delta)$, there are infinitely many $y_n$ which trend to zero such that $F(x_0,y_n)=0$.

Comment: I think your last statement may be over-reaching. If you take $f(x)=x$, then you are looking for the inverse function of $g$. Is $g$ one-to-one on any neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure if I understand what you said. You mean Take $F(x,y)=g(y)-x$. Because $g(y)$ is not one-to-one on any neighborhood of $0$, thus $y$ is not a function of $x$. Is my understanding correct？^-^

Comment: If we take $F(x,y)=g(y)+\sin x$, then in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$, $x$ is also not a function of $y$.

Comment: Yes, to your first comment. No, to this one, as locally $x=\arcsin(g(y))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin By the way, can we say that the Inverse function theorem and Implicit function theorem are equivalent to each other?

Comment: A very different question, but yes. I think you just saw how to prove the Inverse Function Theorem using the Implicit; the other direction is the standard proof.